# Checking the time using VBA?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I need to be able to tell when a record was first input more than 4 hours ago, so now I have the default value of the datetime field as Now(), is there a way of saying:

If datetime > now() + 4 hours?

Thanks,

Bob P

Comment: Hi, first of all,  do you want the time be always "Now" or just a timestamp/snapshot of some field being entered?  Then you can refer to http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/excel-tips-tricks/create-a-timestamp-in-excel-with-formulas/  to set the iteration of a formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the online help topic for `DateAdd()`:

```
If YourDateTimeValue > DateAdd("h", 4, Now()) Then
```